# Is there a specific order one should choose when chaining conditions in querying?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine we have this dataframe as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3], index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

If I want to know the names of people who spent more than 3 (euros), what is the difference between these two approaches:

```
#approach 1:
df[df['Cost']>3]['Name']

#approach 2:
df['Name'][df['Cost']>3]
```

Is there any difference at all or any recommended approach in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do neither of these.  It's [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), and can come back to hurt you unexpectedly.

Instead, it's safer to provide both axis labels at once:

```
df.loc[df['Cost'] > 3, 'Name']
```

This lets you treat `df` as a single entity rather than getting an intermediate object before doing the second filtering/indexing.